# Remove all elements in a list that do not contain valid floating point numbers

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

If I am given a list of string type data, for example if list x contains the following:

```
x = ['98.7','100.5','%','','12.33','&','10']
```

How would I go about removing non floating point elements like `%`, `''`, `10` and `&` from the list? Also, how would I remove NoneType elements as well?

Comment: just use the accepted answer try/except logic from the dupe

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it, almost definitely not the best way:

```
def is_float_string(string):
    try:
        float(string)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return str(float(string)) == string

[ i for i in x if is_float_string(i) ]

#['98.7', '100.5', '12.33']
```

Comment: An explanation for the down-vote would be nice

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this, but the following way is the one I get at the first think:

```
>>> x = ['98.7','100.5','%','','12.33','&','10']
>>> y = [i for i in x if i.strip('0123456789') == '.']
>>> y
['98.7', '100.5', '12.33']
```

Thank you for the comments of **Padraic Cunningham** and **adivk**. I admit my answer was not perfect, but this kind of question always dependent on you real list contains what. I modified it, now it works more generally. However, for real use, one may still need to modify it.

```
y = [i for i in x if i and i != '.' and i.strip('0123456789') in ['.', '-.']]
```

Comment: What about `"-98.7"` or just `"."`?